# Method overloading- cant find symbol

Tags: find, symbols, overloading

```
public class Overloading {

    static void printing() {
        System.out.println("Something being printed here");
    }

    static void printing(String name) {
        System.out.println("hello"+name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printing();
        printing(rizwana);
    }
}
```

I am trying something to check method overloading. But here is the error I got.

```
error: cannot find symbol
            printing(rizwana);
symbol:   variable rizwana
location: class Overloading
```

Answer (score 0):

`rizwana` refers to a variable which you have not made in your code. If you want to pass a string, you should pass it as `"rizwana"`.

Call the method as: `printing("rizwana");`

Answer (score 0):

printing(String name) method will accept a string argument. So you should use printing("rizwana") instead of printing(rizwana). You could this

```
class Overloading {

    static void printing() {
        System.out.println("Something being printed here");
    }

    static void printing(String name) {
        System.out.println("hello "+name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printing();
        printing("rizwana");
    }
}
```